# How can i find admin panel URL of my prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am new to prestashop. 2 days before i installed `prestashop Version 1.6.1.6` in my localhost. But now i forgot its admin panel URL. Is there any way to find out the URL. Any one please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

View the folder where you installed prestashop and from there you can see all the folders.

Default rename the admin folder with admin plus 4 random numbers, ess admin1234.

If you customized the directory differently compare your folders with the default ones.
By default there are:
Adapter, cache, classes, config, controllers, Core, css, docs, download, img, js, localization, log, mails, modules, override, pdf, themes, tools, translation, upload and webservice.

the remainder is the folder admin.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to know the url of admin page from where you can manage your products

Just go to the "administration" (e.g 127.0.0.1/administration) page

You can also check the installation directory for admin or administration folder

If you find any folder named admin or administration then type same name after the   hostname of your website.

Now you will reach to login page if you found admin page of the Prestashop.

Then type the email address and password you provided while installing the Prestashop.